# How set value to custom object property which is as property from another custom object

Tags: objective-c

This is what I have,

```
@inerface Face : NSObject    
   @property (nonatomic, assign) long idO;
   @property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *text;
   @property (nonatomic, assign) Eyes *eyes;
@end

@interface Eyes : NSObject
   @property(nonatomic, assign) NSString *color;
   @property(nonatomic, assign) NSNumber *size;
@end
```

Then I want to do that:

```
Face *f  = [[Face alloc] init];
f.text = @"trying";
f.eyes.color = @"Blue";
f.eyes.size = 0.4f;
NSLog(@"%@ - %@ - %@ ", f.text, f.eyes.color, f.eyes.size);
```

But I only get: "trying - (null) - (null)". How can I do it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Face *f  = [[Face alloc] init]; // Face is Initialization 
f.text = @"trying";
f.eyes.color = @"Blue"; // Eyes is not 
f.eyes.size = 0.4f; 

NSLog(@"%@ - %@ - %@ ", f.text, f.eyes.color, f.eyes.size);
```

(null) - (null) for both instance variable is null due to Object is not init.

---

try with

```
Face *f  = [Face new];
    f.text = @"trying";
    Eyes *eyes = [Eyes new];
    eyes.color = @"Blue";
    eyes.size = @0.4f;
    f.eyes = eyes;
//    f.eyes.color = @"Blue";
//    f.eyes.size = @0.4f;
    NSLog(@"%@ - %@ ", f.text, f.eyes.color)
```

Comment: @Malarkey86 You'll still want to change your object properties to be strong references, otherwise you'll crash when you try and access them again.

Answer (score 3):

You need to retain the content or Archiving :

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject?language=objc

```
  @inerface Face : NSObject
  @property (nonatomic, retain) long idO;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *text;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) Eyes *eyes;
  @end

  @interface Eyes : NSObject
  @property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *color;
  @property(nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *size;
  @end
```

and add init method in NSObject

```
  - (id)init

  {

  if (self = [super init]) {

    self.eyes = [[Eyes alloc]init];

    return self;


   } else {

    return nil;
    }
  }
```

Happy Coding ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to retain the content of the properties.

```
@interface Face : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) long idO;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *text;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Eyes *eyes;
@end

@interface Eyes : NSObject
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *color;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *size;
@end


@implementation Face
@synthesize idO;
@synthesize text;
@synthesize eyes;
@end

@implementation Eyes 
@synthesize color;
@synthesize size;
@end
```

Comment: And don’t forget the `@synthesize` in the implementation.

Comment: Eyes *eyes = [Eyes new];
    eyes.color = @"Blue";
    eyes.size = @0.4f;
    f.eyes = eyes; It will works

Comment: yeeah! @JoyalClifford  You do it nice! Thank you very much